# Jedis.keys() pagination / iterable

Tags: redis, jedis

`Jedis.keys("pattern")` is returning millions of large key strings causing `OutOfMemoryError`. Is there anyway, I can get a paginated result or any iterable resultset?

```
Jedis jcRead = rmgRead.getRedisClientFromPool();
// some more code in b/w

// this is causing OutOfMemoryError as keys returned are huge
Set<String> keys = jcRead.keys("*-json");
```

Comment: Check Jedis' documentation about using the `scan` command

Comment: To expand upon the comment from @ItamarHaber, in most circumstances retrieving keys from Redis through an application client has potential to adversely affect performance.  http://redis.io/commands/KEYS